# Using Mainframe CICS login for JSF Web application

Tags: authentication, jsf, mainframe

Any advise on how to go about implementing a login for a JSF Icefaces based web application, running on GlassFish v3 with Hibernate JPA talking to DB2, with the credentials of the Mainframe CICS application that is used for signing on to terminals?

Answer (score 0):

With CICS, logon and access controls is under program control. Typically in CICS the sign-on screen in CICS is a local Program, so you need to look at this + related mainframe programs. 
But with CICS there is no single way of providing Access Control.

The access programs could
1) Store Logon/access control details in a file or data base (IMS or DB2 etc)
2) Use the Mainframe Access Control (RACF, ACF2 what ever is used at your site) 
3) Some combination of the 2
4) Some thing I have not seen

Also make sure it is CICS you are dealing with, end-Users do not distinguish between CICS and other Mainframe systems.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this with CICS is to specify BASICAUTH on the TCPIPSERVICE definition and create a server URIMAP pointing at the CICS program that will do the actual business logic.

BASICAUTH is just what you would expect, RFC2617.